# How to upsert records on an object with a RecordTypeId?

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a custom object called Product with Record Types (RecordTypeId). On this object, I have two record types: Standard and Model.

My product.csv:

```
Name,Code__c,Family__r.Code__c,RecordTypeId
TV,TV,tv,Standard
GameConsole,GameConsole,gameconsole,Standard
MenShirt,MenShirt,menshirt,Model
LadyShirt,LadyShirt,lady_shirt,Model
```

When I executed this command:

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s Product__c -f csv/product.csv -i Code__c -w 2
```

I got an error:

```
=== Upsert errors
MALFORMED_ID:Record Type ID: id value of incorrect type: Standard:RecordTypeId --
MALFORMED_ID:Record Type ID: id value of incorrect type: Standard:RecordTypeId --
MALFORMED_ID:Record Type ID: id value of incorrect type: Model:RecordTypeId --
MALFORMED_ID:Record Type ID: id value of incorrect type: Model:RecordTypeId --
```

Usually, I have no issue importing other records if there is no "RecordTypeID" field on it. This is the first time I importing records with RecordTypeID. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update:- Make sure to use 18 digit id when you are doing an upsert.

**Description** :- Users may encounter the following errors when working in Data Loader:

```
MALFORMED_ID: Object name id: id value of incorrect type.
MALFORMED_ID:bad id.
MISSING_ARGUMENT:Id not specified in an update call.
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id.
```

**Resolution**  :- Salesforce records are either 15 or 18 characters in length.

Typically when viewed within the organization, they are 15 characters: 00300000003T2PG.
When viewed through Data Loader, API, or Apex, they are 18 characters: 00300000003T2PGAA0.

When you use a 15-character, the system may convert the value to the 18-character representation. Invalid IDs will be rejected with one of the above errors.

> Scenarios: CSV file contains an invalid ID in the ID column or the
>   column

**ID with invalid characters or ID with length less than 15 characters**

- "Insert/Update" operation error: MALFORMED_ID: Object name id: id value of incorrect type
- "Delete" operation error: MALFORMED_ID:bad id

Error resolutions:

- Visit the record in the Organization to verify the ID entered. Keep
  in mind that these IDs are case sensitive.
- Manually convert the 15-character ID to an 18-character ID. See
  article on how to Convert 15-character ID to 18-character ID
- Verify that the correct field is mapped in Data Loader. If you
  inadvertently mapped a Text column to a Lookup field, this error
  might be thrown.

**Missing ID (Blank)**

- Error: MISSING_ARGUMENT:Id not specified in an update call.
- Error Resolution: Enter a valid ID (ID should not be blank)

**Incorrect ID (Update/Upsert)**

- Error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id.
- Error Resolution: ID should be correct (existing ID) and the Owner ID
  listed in the CSV file should have access to the record.

Reference:- [Errors due to invalid IDs during Data Loader import and update](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339844&type=1&mode=1)